# Unable to use google.cloud (storage) from within a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to run the following simple script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.9

from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('my-bucket', prefix='some/path'):
  print(str(blob))
```

This fails as follows:

```
▶ ./test.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pkaramol/Desktop/./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

However, `google-cloud-storage` is already installed:

```
▶ pip freeze | grep -i google
google-api-core==2.11.0
google-auth==2.15.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-cloud-storage==2.7.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.4.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.57.0
```

Why is that?

Comment: is there any difference in output if you use pip3 vs pip? not sure if you are in a virtualized environment

Comment: I have installed `google-cloud-storage` both through `pip` and `pip3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly install the following [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) in your virtual env :

`requirements.txt` file :

```
google-cloud-storage==2.7.0
```

Check of your virtual env was correctly created with the following command :

```bash
which python3
```

Install the package :

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Normally with this package, the import and your program will be correct in your virtual env :

```py
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
for blob in client.list_blobs('my-bucket', prefix='some/path'):
  print(str(blob))
```

You need to be sure you are correctly created your virtual env and installed the expected package inside.